# Why do I need to run a function with if-statements multiple times to reach other statements?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
void _checkbothloc(BuildContext context) {
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.GRANTED) {
    _requestPermission();
  } else if (_serviceEnabled != true) {
    _requestService();
  } else {
    _takePicture(context);
  }
}
```

Why do I have to run `_checkbothloc` 3 times to get to **`_takePicture(context)`**?

Does anyone have the same problem and have found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_takePicture` is only reached the third time because you are using `else` / `else if` blocks. Instead, you would want to set up your function without them:

```dart
void _checkbothloc(BuildContext context) {
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.GRANTED) {
    _requestPermission();
  }

  if (_serviceEnabled != true) {
    _requestService();
  }

  _takePicture(context);
}
```

This way the conditions do not *depend* on each other and will both run no matter what. This also means that `_takePicture` will always be run, just sometimes the permission needs to be requested before and sometimes the service needs to be requested before.

[Learn more](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#control-flow-statements) about **control flow statements** in Dart.

---

You also need to ensure that `_requestPermission` and `_requestService` do not run *asynchronously*. If that is the case, mark your function as **`async`** and **`await`** these.

[Learn more](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) about **asynchronous programming** in Dart.

Comment: but if I use this it will process the takePicture(context) without checking permission and service

Comment: @LambertoFrederickNababan Because you need to await `_requestPermission` and `_requestService`. I linked to a resource explaining the concept of asynchronous programming in Dart. It **will** check request the permission and service.